# I need to get the values and counts for each group from the Tabulator groupHeader to my js and html file

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using Tabulator to log stock alerts from my trading software. I am using Grouping, which groups all alerts for the same stock into one group. I want to get the stock symbol value and each group row count into my js file and/or html file. This data in on the `groupHeaders` bar and in the Tabulator grouping Module, but I am not smart enough to get it separated to be able to use in my auto-trading bot file.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of [Group Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/components#component-group) from the table by calling the `getGroups` function:

```js
var groups = table.getGroups();
```

You can then itterate over each group. the group componenet has a `getKey` function that will return the value that the rows in that group are grouped by. and a `getRows` function that will return an array of the rows from that group.

```js
var groups = table.getGroups();

groups.forEach((group)=>{
    var key = group.getKey();
    var rowCount = group.getRows().length;
});
```

You can then do whatever you like with that data